# Camera intent without external storage permission with photo publicly available

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-storage

all I want is:

- intent for taking picture by camera app;
- taken photo will be available to user publicly - outside my app, even after app uninstall, ideally in the same dir & name as photos taken normally;
- I will be able read the photo once after user returns to my app; no need for persistent access;
- no `EXTERNAL_*_PERMISSION` will be needed;

Currently, this is the most I can get:

```
val values = ContentValues()
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
val fileUri = context.contentResolver.insert(
     MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values
)

Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).apply {
      putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri)
}
```

This has few disadvantages:

- on Android 5-9 it requires external storage permission, otherwise the insert fails (on Android Q it's ok, dunno why);
- the file is created before the user takes the picture - e.g. if I put the intent into chooser with another GET_CONTENT intent, user may choose the empty file;
- the file is stored in `Pictures` folder, not `Camera` - not big deal;

I went through tons of questions and answers, but most of them are outdated (do not use SAF), require permission, etc. I'm looking for solution API21+.